# git push : push to second remote

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

my project has 2 remote git server to push.

it pushes to both of them but fetch from the first one as you can see below:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (push)
origin  http://second_server_ip:port/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (push)
```

some times the first one is going down for deploying new version or some other stuff and in these times if I want to push I will get this error:

```
git push
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

but the second server is up.

so is there any way to push just in the second server?

Comment: `git push origin http://second...`.

Comment: Are you sure both remotes are named origin? Is that even allowed?

Comment: @Julian yes I tested it before, and I pasted my terminal export of command `git remote -v`

Comment: Name the second remote a different name as origin2 or any other than origin.

Comment: @RamKumar I did, but what happened if I want to run command `git pull`? does it fetch from both remotes?

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan You can have merged-remotes. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/6909016) on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

### Way 1 - Sequence

Make second repository push queue in front of first one:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (fetch)
origin  http://second_server_ip:port/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (push)
origin  git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (push)
```

By doing this way you will first push to second server then get error from first server after the push has done.

---

### Way 2 - Different Repository

Add or edit the second repository as a new local repository name likes:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (push)
origin  http://second_server_ip:port/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (push)
backup  http://second_server_ip:port/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git (push)
```

When you want to push to only second server you could:

```
git push backup <branch>
```

---

To add a push url:

```
git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but probably `git -c remote.origin.url=http... push origin ...` would do it